# Unable to retrieve value through resource id

Tags: java, android

I have a following element:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernelb11"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginOne"
        android:background="@color/white1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:text="0" >
```

And i am trying to retrieve it in code like this but all its returning me is `false`:

```
String name = "kernelb11"
int a = this.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "id", getPackageName());
CharSequence asa =  this.getResources().getText(a); //Returning false
String as = (String) this.getResources().getText(a);
```

Due to overall requirment i cant use `findViewById()`

Comment: EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kernelb11); This doesnt work? When you say that you cant use findViewById(), you simply cant or don't want to?

Comment: I dont want to. its a matrix input and total number of `EditText` could vary from 9 to 50.

Comment: can you please mention due to which reason you cant use findViewById()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int a = this.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "id", getPackageName());
```

This identifier points to a `R.id` resource, however [`Resources.getText(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getText%28int%29) expects a `R.string` resource identifier.

You'll first have to find the `EditText` by id and then get its contents. Something like this:

```
String name = "kernelb11"
int a = this.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "id", getPackageName());
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(a);
CharSequence asa =  ed.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

try by removing `this.` in your code

```
String name = "kernelb11";

int layoutID = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "id", getPackageName());
```